# Specifying port for angular in docker compose with Nx using arguments

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, nrwl-nx

Im starting out with Nx and I am trying to dockerize my app for local use (that means i want the angular reloading on changes. This is not for production builds or anything.

I want to have multiple apps in the monorepo so i figures id like a generic dockerfile like this:

```
# base image
FROM node

ARG APP
ARG PORT


# # install chrome for protractor tests
# RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
# RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
# RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -yq google-chrome-stable
# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
COPY decorate-angular-cli.js /app/decorate-angular-cli.js
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
RUN npm install reflect-metadata tslib rxjs @nestjs/platform-express

# add app
COPY . /app
# start app
CMD npm start $APP -- --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT --disableHostCheck=true --poll 100
```

And then use a docker compose like below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  sletsgo.user.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sletsgouserapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SletsGo.User.Api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "2000:2000"
      - "444:443"

  sletsgo.shop:
    container_name: 'SletsGo.Shop'
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY}sletsgo.shop:dev
    build:
        context: SletsGo
        dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
        args:
            - APP=shop
            - PORT="4200"
    ports:
        - '80:4200'
    volumes:
        - './SletsGo:/app'
        - '/app/node_modules'
```

Specifying the app worked perfectly, but for some reason I cant get the port to work.

The docker-compose builds fine, but in the logging of the container it says:

```
> sletsgo@0.0.0 start    
> ng serve "--host" "0.0.0.0" "--port" "--disableHostCheck=true" "--poll" "100"
> nx run shop:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port --disableHostCheck=true --poll=100    
Property 'port' does not match the schema. 'true' should be a 'number'.
```

For some reason my PORT argument is not coming through in the command and i have tried quite a few things but it doesnt seem to make a difference.

- $PORT or ${PORT}
- 4200 or "4200"
- CMD ng serve and CMD npm start  --

Can someone tell me what im doing wrong?
or if i coul specify the port per app on like a project file that would be a great alternative solution.

Comment: Each container runs in its own isolated network space, so it's fine to hard-code `--port 4200`.  That number needs to match the second port number in `ports:` but the first can be anything that's not otherwise in use on the host.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right

Comment: @DavidMaze If you put it in an answer ill accept it. If you van also explain to me why its not working that would be even better. I understand your solution and am still curious.